# Unity3d. Через материал с прозрачным шейдером видны только объекты с sorting layer = default

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

У меня есть 2д игра, я делаю в ней туман войны. Я использую quad с материалом с шейдером прозрачности. И прозрачность работает, но видны почему то только объекты с sorting layer = default.

У объектов есть как минимум sprite renderer.

Вот шейдер

```
Shader "Custom/FogOfWarCG" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Off
        LOD 200
        Lighting off

        pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f_img i) : SV_Target {
                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Не понятно почему так. Можно как то показывать избирательно другие слои?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, что бы магия с прозрачностью для 2d пропала, надо программно выставить для прозрачного слоя sorting layer:

```
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
    meshRenderer.sortingLayerName = "FogOfWar";
    meshRenderer.sortingOrder = 0;
```